# labelling column names in summary dynamically

Tags: r, dplyr

i want to label the names of summary table dynamically so that it can take names of defined already.

so here i am making q25 name dynamically so as if i require to display q25 differently then i can display accordingly.

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("asdf","kjhgf","cvbnm","rtyui","cvbnm","jhfd","cvbnm","sdfghj","cvbnm","dfghj","cvbnm"), 
                 sale=c(27,28,27,16,14,25,14,14,19,18,28), 
                 city=c("CA","TX","MN","NY","TX","MT","HU","KL","TX","SA","TX"), 
                 Dept = c("HH","MM","NN","MM","AA","VV","MM","HU","JJ","MM","ZZ")) 
 
percentile25 <- "25th Percentilen" 
 
t1<-function(dataset,var,name,p25=getOption("percentile25", default = "25th percentile")){ 
  var <- rlang::parse_expr(var)  
   
  tabl1<- dataset %>% filter(!is.na(!!var)) %>% summarise( 
    q25 = quantile(!! var,  type=6, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm=TRUE)[2], 
    N = sum(!is.na(!!var))) 
  summ_tab<-tabl1 %>%   
    mutate(" "= !!name, 
           q25 = q25)  
  summ_tab <- summ_tab %>%  dplyr::rename( 
      q25=!!p25) 
  summ_tab <- summ_tab %>% select(" ",everything(),N) 
  summ_tab 
} 
 
t1(data = df,var = "sale",name = "listd")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that in `dplyr::rename` the new name should be on the LHS, the old name on the RHS. Also, you have to make use of the special assignment operator `:=`, i.e. do `dplyr::rename(!!p25 := q25)`:

```r
library(dplyr)

t1 <- function(dataset, var, name, p25 = getOption("percentile25", default = "25th percentile")) {
  var <- rlang::parse_expr(var)

  tabl1 <- dataset %>%
    filter(!is.na(!!var)) %>%
    summarise(
      q25 = quantile(!!var, type = 6, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm = TRUE)[2],
      N = sum(!is.na(!!var))
    )
  summ_tab <- tabl1 %>%
    mutate(
      " " = !!name,
      q25 = q25
    )
  summ_tab <- summ_tab %>% dplyr::rename(
    !!p25 := q25
  )
  summ_tab <- summ_tab %>% select(" ", everything(), N)
  summ_tab
}

t1(data = df, var = "sale", name = "listd")
#>         25th percentile  N
#> 1 listd              14 11
```

Comment: but the thing is i want to make it dynamic like if i want to display like "25th Percentilen"   or "25th Perc" then i ican display like this or by default is 2th percentile.

Comment: 1. Yep. In your example code it defaults to `"25th percentile"`. As you are using `getOption` you have to set the desired name using `setOption` or pass the name to the `p25` argument. 2. Check your code: According to the error you duplicated `rename`, i.e. `renamerename`.

Comment: ok i will create a another questions for this

Comment: Not sure whether a question is needed. You could e.g. do `t1(data = df, var = "sale", name = "listd", p25 = "25th Percentilen")` or to set the option do `options(percentile25 = "25th Percentilen")`.